# Compare two xml tree nodes and find if a node with a value exists in another using xslt

Tags: xslt, tree, compare, nodes

I have an XML input which is merged format of two xmls:

```
<DATA>
<RECORDS1>
    <RECORD>
        <id>11</id>
        <value>123</value>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <id>33</id>
        <value>321</value>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <id>55</id>
        <value>121113</value>
    </RECORD>
    ...
</RECORDS1>
<RECORDS2>
    <RECORD>
        <id>11</id>
        <value>123</value>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <id>33</id>
        <value>323</value>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <id>44</id>
        <value>12333</value>
    </RECORD>
    ...
</RECORDS2>
```

I need to copy in the output the records in RECORDS1 provided:

1. The records in RECORDS1 doesnot exist in RECORDS2
2. The records in RECORDS1 exists in RECORDS2 but the value is different

Plus if the output could be extended such with an extra field with value as NEW (when does not not exist) as CHANGE (when exists but value is different)

Output

```
<DATA>
<RECORDS>
    <RECORD>
        <id>33</id>
        <value>321</value>
        <kind>Change</kind>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <id>55</id>
        <value>121113</value>
        <kind>New</kind>
    </RECORD>
    ...
</RECORDS>
```

I have applied FOR Loop but as the variable in xslt cant be reset hence it doesnot work.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like a variant of any grouping problem so the usual approaches `for-each-group` in XSLT 2 or later or Muenchian grouping in XSLT 1 should help. Or perhaps just using a key and check for lack of matches suffices to copy the nodes you want.

Comment: any references?

Comment: Well, first tell us which XSLT version you use. In general, you can declare a key with e.g. `<xsl:key name="rec2" match="RECORDS2/RECORD" use="id"/>` and then process only `RECORDS1/RECORD[not(key('rec2', id))]`. If the `value` also matters either combine the key values, easiest in XSLT 3 with `<xsl:key name="rec2" match="RECORDS2/RECORD" composite="yes" use="id, value"/>` and then process only `RECORDS1/RECORD[not(key('rec2', (id, value))]`. With your edit to distinguish between no match and different value you can go for a further key perhaps.

Comment: I am using xslt version 2

Comment: Give the keys a try, for XSLT 2 if I recall it correctly `composite` was not supported but you can use two keys or you can concatenate two values in the `use="concat(id, '|', value)"`.

Comment: Ok and how to distinguish the output between whether the value is different or whether the id is new

Comment: Your verbal description is not quite clear and you have not shown the result you want. Does "The records in RECORDS1 doesnot exist in RECORDS2" refer solely to comparing based on `id`?

Comment: Yes, id is the unique identifier

Comment: I have updated the output in the Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">
    
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="rec2-complete" match="RECORDS2/RECORD" use="concat(id, '|', value)"/>
  <xsl:key name="rec2-id" match="RECORDS2/RECORD" use="id"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="DATA">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="RECORDS1/RECORD[not(key('rec2-complete', concat(id, '|', value)))]"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="RECORDS1/RECORD">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
          <merged>
              <xsl:value-of select="if (key('rec2-id', id)/value != value) then 'changed' else 'new'"/>
          </merged>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

implements the requirements.

Or, to construct the complete result you have shown now, use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">
    
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="rec2-complete" match="RECORDS2/RECORD" use="concat(id, '|', value)"/>
  <xsl:key name="rec2-id" match="RECORDS2/RECORD" use="id"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="DATA">
      <xsl:copy>
          <RECORDS>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="RECORDS1/RECORD[not(key('rec2-complete', concat(id, '|', value)))]"/>
          </RECORDS>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="RECORDS1/RECORD">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
          <kind>
              <xsl:value-of select="if (key('rec2-id', id)/value != value) then 'change' else 'new'"/>
          </kind>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```